# pie chart but in another shape

Tags: charts, data-visualization, graph-visualization

I just wanna ask if it is possible to make a pie chart but in another shape.
An example would be say there were two candidates who ran for governor in a state. I would want to show the results in a chart. I want the shape of the chart to resemble the shape of the geographical location of the state.

I did some digging and this is the only one that showed up which may help me(but not really) https://forums.adobe.com/thread/988130

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your adobe thread implies there are (at least) three issues to consider:

1) you want to show the votes each candidate received as a portion of the area of the state. If your state is nearly square, you could overlay a grid and assign each candidate a number of grid cells according to the votes they received. If the grid cells are county or precinct outlines that works even better, but this isn't a pie chart because a pie chart uses a polar coordinate system.

2) if you really must have a pie chart which is polar, consider that the average viewer may not be able to visually integrate the areas to get meaningful results. Further you will have to integrate the area swept out by the sectors of the pie like a radar screen, and this contour integration is made more difficult by the fact that you must do it numerically. This means you must sample the boundary distance as a function of angular displacement from some center of gravity you have chosen, like the state capitol. But depending on the location of the state capitol, your visual could become even more distorted. Idaho comes to mind.

3) a good compromise might be just to overlay a pie chart on top of a silhouette or map outline of the state with appropriate drop shadows and emphasis to make the pie chart pop as well as the state outline. it would certainly be much quicker as well as much more readable.

Comment: it doesn't have to be a pie chart, I just want the data to be visualized as the shape of the state. Can you cite any alternatives or links on how to tackle this? I'm going with your first insight and just not use a pie chart. Pondering about it more I think I'll just go with your third insight for now, but I would still want to hear more on your first insight.

Comment: Line Integration Wiki is a start. The term contour integration is reserved for the complex plane, but describes what you're doing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral
Numerically you would be computing triangle areas after intersecting the ray from the CG with the endpoint of the boundary segment. It gets hairy if the state is non-convex, which many aren't.